# Microsoft WPF ribbon - how can I add a RibbonTab stored in a Resources.xaml file?

Tags: wpf, resources, ribbon

I have a RibbonTab defined in a Resource file (xaml resources) and i need to add it to the ribbon's tabs collection.

How do i do that? (In xaml)

The Ribbon in xaml is something like that:

```
<Ribbon>
   <Ribbon.Tabs><Ribbon.Tabs/>
</Ribbon>
```

So it holds a collection of tabs, i don't know how to insert a tab stored in the static resources.

Thank you in advance :)
Teodor

edit: This is the [WPF Microsoft ribbon](http://www.codeplex.com/wikipage?ProjectName=wpf&title=WPF%20Ribbon%20Preview)

Edit 2: I tried using `<DynamicResource ResourceKey="MyTabKey" />` but i get this error:

> Property 'Tabs' does not support
>   values of type
>   'DynamicResourceExtension'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you place the RibbonTabs as resources in whatever ResourceDictionary you want:

```
<Application.Resources>
        <r:RibbonTab Label="Tab_A" x:Key="RibControl_A">
            <r:RibbonGroup>
                <r:RibbonButton>
                    <r:RibbonButton.Command>
                        <r:RibbonCommand LabelTitle="CommandA"/>
                    </r:RibbonButton.Command>
                </r:RibbonButton>
            </r:RibbonGroup>
        </r:RibbonTab>
        <r:RibbonTab Label="Tab_B" x:Key="RibControl_B">
            <r:RibbonGroup>
                <r:RibbonButton>
                    <r:RibbonButton.Command>
                        <r:RibbonCommand LabelTitle="CommandB"/>
                    </r:RibbonButton.Command>
                </r:RibbonButton>
            </r:RibbonGroup>
        </r:RibbonTab> 
</Application.Resources>
```

Then you can just reference them as StaticResources

```
<r:Ribbon>
        <r:Ribbon.Tabs>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="RibControl_A" />
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="RibControl_B" />
        </r:Ribbon.Tabs>
</r:Ribbon>
```

That compiles and runs successfully for me.